# Trap click event on dock icon using Qt on Mac

Tags: cocoa, macos, qt

I am trying to get dock click event on dock icon on Mac OS X. I am using Qt-Cocoa. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this for an open-source project. See the code here:
https://github.com/KDAB/Charm/blob/master/Charm/MacApplicationCore.mm

Comment: You've got a broken link here .. if you aren't able to correct it (or add context to this answer beyond the link), this answer will need to be removed.

Comment: Ok, actually it's broken again... I think the file is now located at: https://github.com/KDAB/Charm/blob/master/Charm/MacApplicationCore.mm

Answer (score 0):

In Qt-Carbon, see [Qt4 Mac Dock Icon Click](http://th30z.blogspot.com/2008/08/qt4-mac-dock-icon-click_2711.html). It explains how to install a reopen event handler.

In Qt-Cocoa, you should get the application delegate with `[[NSApplication sharedApplicaion] delegate]` and add you own [applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationShouldHandleReopen%3ahasVisibleWindows%3a) method with [class_addMethod](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod). I have not actually tried this.

Comment: This will not work with Qt-Cocoa. It will work only with Qt-Carbon.

Comment: Your links are broken. If you don't add context to this answer in their absence, this answer will be removed shortly.

Answer (score 0):

On Qt 5.9.1 you can also use a hack without any platform-specific code at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46488514/8695355