# Mac OS X: detect already opened app reopen

Tags: c++, events, macos, macos-carbon

I have a mac os x app with a window which can be hidden.

When the user clicks on the app icon in the dock (or open -b com.mycompany.myapp in the terminal), I would like this window to be shown again (it's a Qt app, so the setVisible(true) thing is known).

**How do I catch the app activation event?**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Trap click event on dock icon using Qt on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767559/trap-click-event-on-dock-icon-using-qt-on-mac).

Comment: @0xced: thanks for the link, I'll check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an Apple Event, so you'll want to use the [Apple Event Manager](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/Apple_Event_Manager/) to register a handler for the [core suite](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/Apple_Event_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCoreEventClass)'s [reopen-application](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/Apple_Event_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kAEReopenApplication) event.

That's how you do it in Carbon. You tagged the question as [carbon] and not [qt], so I assume you want a Carbon solution rather than a Qt solution.

Comment: A Qt solution would also be nice :)

Comment: Here is an howto for your AE solution: http://th30z.blogspot.com/2008/08/qt4-mac-dock-icon-click_2711.html

Comment: Hi, any way to detect if a titlebar less app is minimized through custom handling (basically just hiding it), and then clicked in launchpad? I can get a handler if the dock icon is clicked, I need to get a similar notification when the app is hidden (minimized) and the launchpad icon/Applications folder icon is clicked as well so that I can unhide it..

Comment: @AttitudeMonger: Apps and windows are two different things. You can check whether your window is borderless by looking at its `styleMask`. You can do this in your reopen handler—Launchpad, AFAIK, doesn't do anything different from double-clicking your app in the Finder or clicking on it in the Dock.